# how to get data from another ajax based function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function get_images(off){
    $.post('images_pro.php', {fn: 'get_images', args: [off, lm, dim, 'e']}, function(data){
        console.log(data);  // this works
        return data;
    });
}

$('.mmdim').on('click', function(){
    var data = get_images(0);
    console.log(data);  // undefined
});
```

How to get `data` from the first to the second function?

Comment: return is not a function. it is a statement, simply use return data;

Comment: you can use await or callbacks and use `return data`

Comment: @SandeepK. tried `return data` - the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there are 2 options to do that:

Method 1 (using [done](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function):

```
function get_images(off){
    return $.post('images_pro.php', {fn: 'get_images', args: [off, lm, dim, 'e']});
}

$('.mmdim').on('click', function(){
    get_images(0).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Method 2 (using [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)):

```
function get_images(off){
    return $.post('images_pro.php', {fn: 'get_images', args: [off, lm, dim, 'e']});
}

$('.mmdim').on('click', async function(){
    var data = await get_images(0);

    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: method 1 - in case `data` is a json string and using `data = JSON.parse(data)` I'm getting error - `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: @qadenza That message appears when you're trying to parse an invalid json format input to a json. Could you please show the data?